# Qt5, set text size in lineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to change text size (and font too) in Qt5 QLineEdit class?
I looked in the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) but found no solution.

```
//the font I want to use to display a message
QFont littleFont("Courier New", 10);

//my message
QString strS = "hi all"

// setting the message in my lineEdit object
ui.lineEdit->setText(strS);
```

Comment: You probably forgot this call: `ui.lineEdit->setFont(littleFont);` before setting the text?

Comment: You didn't look thoroughly enough. QLineEdit inherits QWidget so all it's members are available to you, including `void setFont(const QFont &)` method. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others said in the comments:

You can set the font to the line edit using this line:

```
ui.lineEdit->setFont(littleFont);
```

This member function can be found in the Documentation by clicking on

> [> List of all members, including inherited members](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit-members.html)

If you do not set all attributes of the Font be aware that the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#font-prop) states:

> When you assign a new font to a widget, the properties from this font
>   are combined with the widget's default font to form the widget's final
>   font. You can call fontInfo() to get a copy of the widget's final
>   font. The final font is also used to initialize QPainter's font.